# ProgressDialog em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, thread

Estou tentando criar um form semelhante ao ProgressDialog no android, em C#..

A idéia seria que acontecesse isso:

```
//criar o controle na thread principal
frmWaitingProgress  fl = new frmWaitingProgress(this);
fl.Show(this);

//fazer todo o processamento na thread principal
for(long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue; i++)
{

}

//depois de fazer o que tiver que fazer simplismente fecha o form
fl.Close();
```

E no meu `frmWaitingProgress`, outra thread seria responsável por atualizar o gif de "aguarde".

```
//Então para isso sobescrevi o OnLoad do método e criei minha thread
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Thread trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadUpdate));
    trd.Start();
}

private void ThreadUpdate()
{
    while (this.IsDisposed == false)
    {
        if (this.pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            { 
                this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
                this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                this.pictureBox1.Update();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            pictureBox1.Update();
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Mas o form não é atualizado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Form do jeito que deveria ficar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que existe a possibilidade de usar o `backgroundworker` ou fazer o processamento em outra thread, mas gostaria de fazer deste jeito para não me "preocupar" nos lugares que vou usar.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer isto, ou se me dizer se isto é possível?

Edição com a sugestão do Henrique

```
public class frmTeste 
{
    Task task;
    Thread bgThread;
    public void ShowTest()
    {
        task = new Task(() => {
            bgThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            new frmWaitingProgress().ShowDialog();
            //new frmWaitingProgress().Show();
        });

        task.Start();
    }
}
```

E na chamada..

```
 frmTeste fl = new frmTeste();
 fl.ShowTest();
 for(long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue; i++)
 {
    Application.DoEvents(); //tentei coloca um DoEvents()..
 }
```

Comment: Sua ideia não tá legal. Você quer abrir um form que mostre progresso infinito, isso?

Comment: Infinito por causa do gif? Sim... mas depois do que tiver que fazer eu fecho o form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que você terá que utilizar programação assíncrona, este exemplo abaixo funciona sem muito trabalho:

```
public class myForm : Form {
    Task task;
    Thread bgThread;

    public myForm() {

    }

    // Inicia a task
    public void InvokeProgressDialog() {

        // Inicialização e setup do seu progressDialog
        task = new Task(() => {

            // registra a bgThread
            bgThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

            // chama o progressDialog (form)
            new ProgressDialog().ShowDialog();

        });

        task.Start();
    }

    // aborta a thread (a qual a task está)
    public void CancelProgressDialog() {
        bgThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Você pode invocar/cancelar a progressDialog chamando os metodos `InvokeProgressDialog` e `CancelProgressDialog` de qualquer contexto que possui acesso a classe myForm. Note que dois contextos estão sendo exibidos:

- Contexto da progressDialog;
- Contexto de onde é chamado o método `InvokeProgressDialog`.

> Note que apenas uma bgThread é registrada, se precisar, pode expandir este conceito registrando mais threads.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta,  vou testar agora de tarde,  mas ja vou dar +1 agora.

Comment: Tentei deste jeito, o `ShowDialog` é chamado dentro do `Task`, mas o form nem abre, tentei apenas `Show` e nada aconteceu também :/

Comment: Que estranho, pode mostrar o trecho de código ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Henrique  inserindo o código.

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni cara, aqui roda normal... vc já debugou com breakpoints? Não aparece nenhum erro? O que tem no construtor do frmWaitingProgress ?

Comment: Sim já debuguei, não aparece nenhum erro, ele chama o `new ProgressDialog().ShowDialog()`, mas durante o `for`, ele fica processando e não abre a tela, você tentou colocar um `for` até `long.MaxValue`?, no construtor não tem nada de mais... Vou fazer um projeto a parte para testar.

Comment: Sim, fiz com for infinito logo abaixo da chamada da método `InvokeProgressDialog`. Teu form nem abrir que está estranho.. Se quiser posso postar todo o código pra vc ver, mas é muito simples mesmo. No meu progressDialog tenho um picturebox que tem um gif, simples assim.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49799/discussion-between-marco-giovanni-and-henrique).